# Gvim: Empty bottom bar appears on re-sourcing vimrc

Tags: vim

I recently decided to migrate to Gvim, and noticed that some of my gui-specific settings are borked.

I have defined an autocommand to re-source $MYVIMRC upon writing to it, and upon re-sourcing it (this does not happen on the initial startup), an empty bar appears on the bottom. I believe it is the bar that is meant to contain the horizontal scrollbar.

When I attempt to remove the scrollbar using

```
:set guioptions-=b
```

nothing happens. However, if I add it first and then remove it,

```
:set guioptions+=b
:set guioptions-=b
```

it disappears.

I thought this might be related to how and when I am defining my `guioptions`. This is the relevant part of my .vimrc:

```
set guioptions-=m              " GUI: Disable Menu 
set guioptions-=r              " GUI: Disable right scrollbar
set guioptions-=T              " GUI: Disable Toolbar
```

I attempted to put this in an `augroup` like this

```
augroup GuiWidgets
  au!
  set guioptions-=m              " GUI: Disable Menu 
  set guioptions-=r              " GUI: Disable right scrollbar
  set guioptions-=T              " GUI: Disable Toolbar
augroup end
```

but it made no difference.

What can be the source of this problem?

**EDIT 1** - Added .vimrc

```
let mapleader = ','
inoremap jj <Esc>
set nocompatible


"********************************
" PLUGINS
"********************************

if has('vim_starting')
  set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/
endif

call neobundle#begin(expand('~/.vim/bundle/'))

NeoBundleFetch 'Shougo/neobundle.vim'

NeoBundle 'benmills/vimux'
NeoBundle 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
NeoBundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
NeoBundle 'kana/vim-textobj-entire'
NeoBundle 'kana/vim-textobj-user'
NeoBundle 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
NeoBundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
NeoBundle 'godlygeek/tabular'
NeoBundle 'surround.vim'
NeoBundle 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
NeoBundle 'Shougo/vimproc.vim'
NeoBundle 'Shougo/unite.vim'
NeoBundle 'Shougo/vimshell.vim'
NeoBundle 'c.vim'

call neobundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

NeoBundleCheck


"******************************
" PLUGIN SETTINGS
"******************************

nnoremap <C-p> :Unite file_rec/async:! -silent -start-insert -auto-resize<CR>


"******************************
" PLUGIN MAPPINGS
"******************************

map <Space> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)

cnoreabbrev bi Unite neobundle/install
cnoreabbrev bu Unite neobundle/update
cnoreabbrev bc NeoBundleClean

nmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /=<CR>
vmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /=<CR>
nmap <Leader>a: :Tabularize /:\zs<CR>
vmap <Leader>a: :Tabularize /:\zs<CR>
nmap <Leader>a# :Tabularize /#<CR>
vmap <Leader>a# :Tabularize /#<CR>


"******************************
" GENERAL SETTINGS
"******************************

set t_Co=256                   
let g:molokai_original=0       
colorscheme molokai            
filetype plugin indent on      
syntax on                      

set complete-=t                
set gfn=Source\ Code\ Pro\ 10  
set encoding=utf-8             
set number                     
set lazyredraw                 
set completeopt-=preview       
set ttyfast                    
set backspace=indent,eol,start 

set hidden                     
set showmatch                  
set wildmode=longest:list,full 
set wildmenu                   
set shortmess+=I               
set showcmd                    
set showmode                   
set clipboard=unnamed          

set history=50                 
set nrformats=                 
set autoread                   
set ruler                      
set laststatus=2               
set scrolloff=8                
set visualbell                 
set splitright                 

set smarttab                   
set autoindent                 
set expandtab                  
set tabstop=4                  
set shiftwidth=4               
set softtabstop=4              
set ignorecase smartcase       
set gdefault                   

set incsearch                  
set hlsearch                   
set nobackup                   
set noswapfile                 
set ttimeoutlen=50             
set relativenumber             
set cursorline                 
set cc=80                      

set guioptions-=m             
set guioptions-=r             
set guioptions-=T             
"set guioptions=

match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'


"***************************
" GENERAL MAPPINGS
"***************************

map cn <Esc>:cn<CR>
map cp <Esc>:cp<CR>
nmap <CR> o<Esc>k
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>O
nnoremap <leader>v :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
nnoremap <leader>h  :let @/ = ""<CR>
nnoremap n nzz
nnoremap <silent> <leader>; :call setline('.', getline('.').';')<CR>
nnoremap <leader>q <C-w>q<CR>
nnoremap <leader>w :w<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>d :bp\|bd #<CR>
nnoremap <leader>c :cd %:p:h<CR>
cnoreabbrev ci( %ci(
cnoreabbrev ci) %ci)
cnoreabbrev ci[ %ci[
cnoreabbrev ci[ %ci]
cnoreabbrev ci{ %ci{
cnoreabbrev ci} %ci}


"***************************
" AUTOCOMMANDS
"***************************

" Auto-source .vimrc
augroup Vimrc
    au!
    au bufwritepost .vimrc source $MYVIMRC
augroup end

" Filetype-specific settings
augroup Filetypes
    au!
    "au FileType c nmap <leader>r :SCCompileRun<CR>
    au FileType c nmap <leader>r :make\|!./%:r<CR>
    au FileType c setlocal sw=2 sts=2 
    au FileType ruby nmap <leader>r :call RunByFiletype("ruby")<CR>
augroup end
```

**EDIT 2** - Added pictures
 (sorry for the small size)

On startup
[image: On startup]

After sourcing .vimrc (the empty scrollbar container appears)
[image]

After running :set guioptions+=b (the horizontal scrolling bar is added to the container)
[image]

After running :set guioptions-=b (the horizontal container disappears)
[image]

After running :set gfn=Source\ Code\ Pro\ 10 (the bar reappears)
[image]

Comment: I've traced the problem down to the `set gfn=<fontname>` line. Not sure why it happens yet.

Comment: Can you add an image of the edge, originally, after `+=b`, after `-=b` and after `gfn=<fontname>`?

Comment: Added images of the bar after requested commands!

Comment: The shades of grey do not quite match up. I'm newb, but what happens if you simply resize window height with the mouse? Does the light-grey region remain difference between multiples of font height and window size?

Comment: Try messing with the font size, see if you can get the empty grey region to disappear and reappear. I suspect it's not an empty scroll bar, but simply the window edge bearing it's ugly head. Are you on a Linux? Which distro and DE?

Comment: I can confirm this issue does not occur in Gvim on Windows. The problem may lie in me using a tiling window manager, Awesome WM on Arch Linux!

Comment: Perhaps the tiling manager is forcing the window size. Do you understand what I mean by dark region is multiple of font height. I will add an image below to illustrate what I am imagining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Vim in a terminal

[image]

Another example where I've tiled GVim to the upper right corner

[image]

The normal edge size is on the left, while on the right, is a forced edge size due to tiling and font height.

Comment: Hm. I'll give this a try in a non-tiling WM and see if this is the root of the problem.

Comment: You were indeed correct! The issue does not occur using LXDE. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a block to initialize the GUI-specific options I wanted to set at startup and to not be subject of resourcing of .vimrc. I will no longer see the "instant effect" of changing the guifont in $MYVIMRC, but this will keep the bottom-bar from appearing.

```
if has('gui_running')
    if has('vim_starting') 
        set gfn=Source\ Code\ Pro\ 10
        set guioptions-=m
        set guioptions-=T
        set guioptions-=r
        set guioptions+=c
    endif
endif
```